# Folder structure within an R project to include .bib file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on a R project

My file structure is as follows. The Rmd file is within the analysis` folder.

```
Rproj
analysis
    -file.rmd
data
    -data.csv
```

I want to include my `references.bib` file in the root directory. 
The Yaml on my Rmd is as follows:

```
output:
  Templates::report:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 5
    fig_width: 8
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
    toc: false
```

However my references don't seem to work with my `.bib` file in the root directory, but works when in the "analysis" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the `.bib` file in your YAML header. If it's in the parent folder of your Rmd file, I think something like this should work:

```
output:
  Templates::report:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 5
    fig_width: 8
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
    toc: false
bibliography: ../references.bib
```

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html